# How to use non-latin characters as a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am newbie with javascript and I am trying to build my first app with it. I want for the app to change language based on a user selection.
I thought about creating Arrays for my buttons etc holding the 3 languages:

```
var welcomeMessage=[("λσκηφαλκσφ"),"Welcome!", "Добро пожаловать"]
```

This doesnt work! Any suggestions on how to do this? Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What is your file saved as? Thought so.. Save it as UTF-8 and output as UTF-8.

Comment: What do you mean by 'this doesn't work'? It works fine for me.

Comment: It does work? http://jsfiddle.net/QXjU2/

Comment: Are using HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: Have you lost interest since posting this question?

Comment: @Moob: not at all! when I try to save the js file it gives me save failed null charset

Comment: thought I d try to get the Unicode encoding of the words in non-Latin characters done online and used the decodeURI function to insert it and it allowed me to save

Comment: btw...yes using HTML and javascript

Comment: this is my html:  <script src="js/keeptrack.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Answer (score 0):

If it works or not depends on the encoding of your file and the encoding the server sends in response headers. This should work if you choose `UTF-8` as your encoding.